# connect mysql from php without yum command manually

Tags: mysql, php, redhat, linux, rpm

I am trying to connect to mysql from php, it says i have not configured mysql-php, call to undefined function:mysql_connect();. My server is not registered with RHN, hence i cannot yum install php-mysql. How do i configure php-mysql connection without yum install. Thanks.

cat /etc/*-release

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga)
```

---

rpm -qa |grep php |grep mysql

```
php-mysql-5.1.6-5.el5
```

---

rpm -qa | grep -i php

```
 php-common-5.1.6-5.el5
 php-5.1.6-5.el5
 php-cli-5.1.6-5.el5
 php-devel-5.1.6-5.el5
 php-pdo-5.1.6-5.el5
 php-mysql-5.1.6-5.el5
```

---

netstat -vat |grep sql

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                     *:*                         LISTEN
```

---

***phpinfo()***

**system:**
Linux us-master.idyabroo.com 2.6.18-8.el5xen #1 SMP Fri Jan 26 14:29:35 EST 2007 x86_64

**Configure Command**

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux' '--
 target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-  
  prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--
datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--
libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--
mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' 
'--    with-
libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '-    -
disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' 
'--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-
 native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-
dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr' '--with-
pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-
magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' 
'--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid' '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos'
 '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-
shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio' '--with-mime-
magic=/etc/httpd/conf/magic' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--
with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' **'--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--without-odbc'** '--disable-dom'
 '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-
xmlwriter'
```

**'--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--without-odbc'**

how to **--with-mysql**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to resompile if you've got dynamic loading support enabled.

You've already got the php-mysql rpm installed - so either it's not configured properly your php.ini or it has dependencies which have not been installed (which is a tricky scenarion to create).

running rpm --verify php-mysql will perform some basic checks in the install.

rpm -q -l will list the files in the rpm:

```
[symcbean@example ~]$ rpm -q -l php-mysql
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so
/usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so
/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
```

Check these files exist and are readable by your webserver uid (rpm -q -l php-mysql | xargs ls -l).

Check that the location of the php modules matches the extension_dir in your php.ini, which should also have dl enabled. NB use phpinfo() to findout where your php.ini is located.

The EPEL service provides third party add-ons to RHEL, not the RH supplied packages. But you can download individual rpms (if you have a current RHEL subsription from [access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/)). If you don't have a subscription (and therefore you're not bothered about RH support), the [Centos rpms](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17008665/dir/centos_5/com/php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386.rpm.html) *should* be binary compatible (see link for dependencies). There are also other people providing RH compatible rpms (try [rpm search](http://rpm.pbone.net))

Answer (score 0):

You should look into installing the EPEL repository for your release of RedHat. This is going to be way easier to maintain than starting to compile software from sources.

See : https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL